# query to get number of cell's questionn , a specific user has got

Tags: sql, database

i have four tables

1. user-question contains two columns: questionID, userID, the questions that the user answers.
2. question-cell contains two columns: questionID, cellID the questions that will be asked in cell.
3. question-place contains two columns: questionID, placeID the questions that will be asked in place.
4. question contains two columns: ID, text

i want to know the number of cells question that the user (userID=3) has got

i think like this

```
select questionID 
FROM `question-cell` 
WHERE questionID in 
    (select questionID 
    from `user-question` 
    WHERE userID = 3 AND competitionID = 4 
    group by competitionID, userID)
```

and i want to know if that is write , because i am working on Notebad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the following query.  Group Bys will not work in sub queries and you had quotes in places where you shouldn't have them.

```
select count(*) FROM question-cell WHERE questionID in (select questionID from 
user-question WHERE userID = 3 AND competitionID = 4)
```